# Pymaxflow installation on Mac

Tags: python, max-flow

I was trying to install the newest version of Pymaxflow through git. When I downloaded the source code and ran

```
python setup.py build
```

it reports an error:

```
maxflow/src/_maxflow.cpp:610:10: fatal error: 'ios' file not found
#include "ios"
     ^~~~~
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So, where can I find this 'ios' file? The following is my gcc configuration:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```